# Casting in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to add 3 letters to my data in SSIS (OLE DB Source). Source format of my data is float, so first I cast it to int, next to char and add to string:

> 'ABC'+cast(cast(KL.ID as int) as char(46)) Id

and I get in MS 2008R2 something like

> ABC443400

but when I run this code in SSIS I get:

> [OLE DB Source [1]] Error: There was an error with output column "Id" (37) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (11). The column status
>   returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential
>   loss of data.".
>
> [OLE DB Source [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "output column "Id"
>   (37)" failed because error code 0xC0209072 occurred, and the error row
>   disposition on "output column "Id" (37)" specifies failure on
>   error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
>   PrimeOutput method on component "OLE DB Source" (1) returned error
>   code 0xC0209029.  The component returned a failure code when the
>   pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code
>   is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline
>   stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.

In Advanced Editor of OLE DB Source:

> External Columns: DataType -
>   string[DT_STR], Length - 49, Output Columns: DataType -
>   double-precision float[DT_R8]

In Advanced Editor of OLE DB Destination:

> External Columns: DataType - string[DT_STR], Length - 50,

Comment: How do you mean "running this code in SSIS"?  It looks like T-SQL code to me, so I'm guessing that it's in the SQL query which supplies the OLE DB Source?  If that is where it is, then it's not the code you've quoted that's causing the problem (SSIS doesn't execute that).  The problem will be that output column "Id" is of the wrong data type.  Look at the Advanced Editor in SSIS to see what data type it is (SSIS often guesses wrong)

Comment: DECLARE @f FLOAT = 443400.253243 SELECT 'ABC' + cast(cast(@f AS INT) AS VARCHAR(10)) This runs without any error in ssms

Comment: According to @SebTHU, the error is in the output column of OLE DB Source. Source columns with no fixed data types makes SSIS guess data types based in results. To prevent this you have to specify a fixed data type in source query: `CAST('ABC'+CAST(CAST(KL.ID as INT) as CHAR(46))) AS CHAR(50)`

Comment: @Balde: true, explicitly casting the whole thing in SQL should work.  Instead of this, I usually use the Advanced Editor to "slap" SSIS into using a column type and length which will work and won't be truncated.

Comment: @SebTHU Yes. Please check my update.

Comment: @Balde I got the same errros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your latest update.  The OLEDB Destination column type shouldn't be relevant (though it will become relevant later, probably), because the error is occurring on the OLEDB Source.

The problem is in the OLEDB Source Output Columns: Id is defined as double (RT_8).  In Advanced Editor, you can change the datatype of the External Column "Id" (if you're happy with the current setting - and it looks fine: 49 characters - then change it to something else and then back again).  This should automatically update the Output Column type as well (but check and manually change that as well to match).

Further down the line, it sounds as though you're writing this column to an OLEDB Dest.  You may have to change the column type in your destination table to varchar(50) or nvarchar(50) (matching the SSIS-internal "Id" column type) and let SSIS read the table metadata again - or force a type change with Advanced Editor.  Once you change the column type in the source, SSIS *should* complain that there's a type mismatch in the OLEDB Dest, but I won't guarantee this!

What it comes down to, I think, is SSIS guessing the wrong type for your Id column from the start.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're writing SQL code directly in the OLE DB Source. It seems to be a problem with the metadata concerning the column ID you're working with.

Check the datatype and/or the length of the string in the advanced settings of the OLE DB Source.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this using Derived Column:

> "ABC" + (DT_STR,47,1250)Id

and Data Conversion:

> string[DT_STR], 50

But is it possible to do it using only SQL?