# How to use a CAST statement in OLE DB source in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am have a OLE DBb source from a server. I have two columns in it called [name] and [address] both are currently `nvarchar(4000)` at the source. I wanted to convert these columns to `varchar(max)` at the source side so that we can get remove the 4000 character limit. Normally I would just go to the advanced editor and change the type to NTEXT stream but I'm getting error as:

> not able to retrieve long data for column [NAME].

Therefore I've decided to go for cast statement

```
Select
  \[Name\]
  ,\[Address\]
From \[Table\]
```

This is how I normally extract from SQL query in the source. It works fine

Now I'm trying to CAST the columns to varchar max

```
Select
  Cast(Name AS varchar(max)) AS name
  , Cast(Address AS varchar(max)) AS address
From table
```

But this will not parse in the query editor. I get error at 'name'

I also tried something like:

```
Select \* from table
Cast(name as varchar(max))
```

This query parses through but if I see the column mappings the column NAME is still in `nvarchar(4000)`.

Comment: Hello welcome to SO! Do you think [this post can help you?]https://stackoverflow.com/q/36013452/1389394)

Comment: I suspect you don't need all the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can always wrap an object (schema, table, column) with the square brackets `[]`. You can probably use a double quote `""` but I think there's some setting that can pooch that so we'll just focus on the use of brackets.

The syntax for a [SELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql) statement does explain what is/is not valid syntax so your `SELECT * FROM table Cast(name as varchar(max))` violates that spec so no surprise there. As well as all the back slashes you've riddled your example with.

[image]

Name and Address are "special" to SQL as they get highlighted blue but they're not reserved words such that I can't *just* reference them. Where as my `ORDER`  table, yeah that breaks parsing as `SELECT * FROM ORDER ORDER BY Col1`

In the case of my ORDER table, I need to always wrap it with brackets thus `SELECT * FROM [ORDER] ORDER BY Col1` totally works.

When you perform an operation on a column in your select statement, you're generating a new column and therefore, need to give it a name. Being a lovely language, you have two mechanisms for assigning an alias aka a new name.

- You can use the AS convention `col1 AS newCol1`
- You can use Assignment `newCol2 = col2`

I favor AS but an excellent argument for assignment is the optionality of the AS itself `col1 ThisWorksToo`

```
SELECT
    CAST(T.Name AS varchar(MAX)) AS [Name]
,   CAST(T.Address AS varchar(MAX)) [Address]
,   [NonBlueColumn] = CAST(T.NonBlueColumn AS varchar(MAX))
FROM
    #t AS T;
```

SSIS is happy with either syntax in the OLE/ADO Source components as well as in Execute SQL Tasks.